# How to create a web link - after click browser opens

Tags: android

I need to create a simple link in my Android app. Let's say that it would display text "Google" and after user clicks on it, http://google.com opens in web browser. What is the easiest way to do this? The link should change color whhen it's in pressed state.

Answer (score 0):

The android library provides [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example
http://jtomlinson.blogspot.in/2010/03/textview-and-html.html

and for changing color 
android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"